# Compare Json objects

Tags: arrays, json, parsing

I am trying to compare two json objects in javascript.
In one place i have this json

[image]

In the other place i have this json:

[image]

I am trying to check if any of the elements in the first json is in the second json. The order doesn't mather. For example:

```
 If ({name: "melocoton", year=2018}) is in both json {
    var value=true;
}
 else {
    var value = false;
}
```

I have tried parsing both json and this function:

```
const found_prod_and_year = json1.some(r => json2.includes(r))
```

But this returns false always.
This functions comparing simple arrays like [5,6] and [5,3] , returns true because 5 is in both arrays.

Any help would be awesome.
Thank you so much!

Comment: It looks like the in your example, it is a regular object and not a JSON

Comment: I have used JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object1)) to get what appears in the images